# invalid certificate chain for aws cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I cannot add my Comodo SSL certificate to aws cloudfront. I get the error:

I have received the following files from them:

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
COMODORSAOrganizationValidationSecureServerCA.crt
STAR_myapp_com.crt
```

I also have the private key.

Following this blog: https://guillaumemaka.com/2015/05/06/install-your-comodo-certificates-to-amazon-aws.html

```
openssl x509 -in ./AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt -outform pem -out ./pem/AddTrustExternalCARoot.pem
openssl x509 -in ./COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt -outform pem -out ./pem/COMODORSAAddTrustCA.pem
openssl x509 -in ./COMODORSAOrganizationValidationSecureServerCA.crt -outform pem -out ./pem/COMODORSAOrganizationValidationSecureServerCA.pem
openssl x509 -in ./cdn_guillaumemaka_com.crt -outform pem -out ./pem/cdn_guillaumemaka_com.pem
openssl rsa -in ./private.key -outform PEM -out private.key.pem
```

Now, I created the certificate chain using the commands:

```
$ cat ./pem/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.pem > ./pem/CAChain.pem
$ cat ./pem/COMODORSAAddTrustCA.pem >> ./pem/CAChain.pem
$ cat ./pem/AddTrustExternalCARoot.pem >> ./pem/CAChain.pem
```

Finally, I uploaded the certificate using:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name CDNServerCertificate --certificate-body file://cdn_guillaumemaka_com.pem --private-key file://private.key.pem --certificate-chain file://CAChain.pem --path /cloudfront/production/
```

When I try to add this to my cloudfront distribution, I get this error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.InvalidViewerCertificateException: The specified SSL certificate doesn't exist, isn't in us-east-1 region, isn't valid, or doesn't include a valid certificate chain. (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidViewerCertificate; Request ID: 90ee29ae-068e-11e8-xxxx-62197a5115b7)
```

How do I create a valid certificate bundle?

Comment: Did you move your private.key.pem to the same folder as CAChain.pem and cdn_guillaumemaka_com.pem? In the lines above the private.key.pem ends up in a different place, but then you reference them with the same path in the IAM line.

Comment: yeah, that I did!